# Inserting outline in a given matrix using a show instance, in Haskell

Tags: haskell, matrix, instance, show

I know this question is similar to the one specified as duplicate, but I changed my approach so any help for this particular case would be appreciated.

I would like to create a show instance for every given matrix that will not only visualize its contents, but also create an outline with columns.

My code so far is the following:

```
instance Show a => Show (Mat a) where
  show  =  unlines . map (unwords . map ((++" |") . show)) . mrows
```

The output I get is:

```
1 | 2 | 3 |
4 | 5 | 6 |
```

What I could not perform is to insert lines above, below and in-between the matrix, to be looking like the following example:

```
+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
+---+---+---+
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thought is that `show` is probably the wrong place for this. There is a general principle that `read` should be the inverse of `show`. While you haven't got a `Read` instance, its still usual to put pretty-printing in a separate function. However that is just a style thing.

[Incorrect statement deleted]

You want to be able to handle rows of varying length by padding them out with blanks (as I understand it). You therefore need to find the maximum row length. You probably want something like

```
where
   cols = maximum $ map length rows
```

Then you can generate your separator line using something like

```
   sepLine = '+' : concat (replicate cols "----+")
```

Comment: IMO it's fine for a `Show` instance to pretty-print the result. Just, it should still be valid Haskell syntax. That's something [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) really does quite nicely.

Comment: As I'm a Haskell beginner, I don't think using an external library would be useful at this point. I'm mostly trying to understand how things work. Your suggestion above means that I have to replace unlines and unwords with another expression and then define a line separator?

Comment: @JohnStef, I'm using only stuff in the prelude. As for my comment about "unlines" and "unwords", please ignore it. I had "lines" and "unlines" swapped in my head.